# How to rotate canvas bitmap without cut?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am new to android,

I want to rotate a canvas bitmap without cut.

I used the below code, but when I rotate the image it cuts off a portion from the bitmap.

```
 float px = iv_photo.getWidth()/2;
 float py = iv_photo.getHeight()/2;
 matrix.postTranslate(-canvas.getWidth()/2, -canvas.getHeight()/2);
 matrix.postRotate(90);
 matrix.postTranslate(px, py);
 canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```

Comment: Do you have tried to rotate from xml layout  using android:rotate="yourAngle" .

Comment: Is the canvas bigger than your bitmap ? Why are you using two different points for the translation?  matrix.postTranslate(-px, -py)

Comment: Can i remove? matrix.postTranslate(-canvas.getWidth()/2, -canvas.getHeight()/2);

Comment: yes, you can remove that.